# How do I transpose an empty numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an 'empty' 2D array in numpy as

`arr = np.array([[[], [], []], [[], [], []]])`.

When I do `np.transpose(arr)`, I get the result: `[]`, instead of the expected:

`[[[],[]],[[],[]],[[],[]]]`.

Comment: the shape is changeing nevertheless. `arr.shape` : `(2, 3, 0)` and `arr.T.shape` : `(0, 3, 2)`

Comment: Do you have a clear sense of why you need this array?  Your question should include the fuller description that you gave in a comment (2d containing lists as elements).

Answer (score 0):

You get an empty array [] with the right shape. Mind that also arr is an empty array [].

```
arr = np.array([[[], [], []], [[], [], []]])
print(arr, arr.shape)
t = arr.T
print(t, t.shape)

[] (2, 3, 0)
[] (0, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Is there a way to 'remove' the last `0` dimension? I want to treat the innermost `[]`s in the original `arr` as just _things inside the array_, not as another dimension. Basically, I want the transpose to have a shape of `(3, 2)`, with `[]` as its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what your expression produces:

```
In [41]: arr = np.array([[[], [], []], [[], [], []]])                           
In [42]: arr                                                                    
Out[42]: array([], shape=(2, 3, 0), dtype=float64)
In [43]: print(arr)                                                             
[]
In [44]: print(repr(arr))                                                       
array([], shape=(2, 3, 0), dtype=float64)
```

The print shows the `str` display, while `repr` is a fuller one that tells us `shape` and `dtype`.  `np.array` has followed the `[]` all the way down, making a 3d array that has float elements.  But since the lowest level is created from `[]`, it has size 0 dimension, and overall the array has 0 elements.

What you want, based on the comment, is a (2,3) array with object dtype.  This can hold objects such as lists.  But making that with `np.array` is tricky.  A more general tool is to make one with the right shape and dtype.

I like to use `empty` for this, since is fills the object array with `None` elements.  (In a numeric dtype `np.empty` has other problems, but for object it's nice.)

```
In [45]: arr = np.empty((2,3), dtype=object)                                    
In [46]: arr                                                                    
Out[46]: 
array([[None, None, None],
       [None, None, None]], dtype=object)
```

But trying to assign a list to elements of such an array can be tricky:

```
In [47]: arr[:]=[]                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-b5ed8d639464> in <module>
----> 1 arr[:]=[]

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (2,3)
In [48]: np.full((2,3),[])                                                      
...
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (2,3)
```

`full` has the same problem.  In addition assignment like this, if it worked, would put the same list in each slot, the equivalent of making a list with `[[]]*3`.  We want a new `[]` in each slot.

We can do this in the 2d `arr`, but the iteration is simpler with a 1d (which can be reshaped later):

```
In [49]: arr = np.empty(6, object)                                              
In [50]: arr                                                                    
Out[50]: array([None, None, None, None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [51]: for i in range(6): arr[i]=[]                                           
In [52]: arr                                                                    
Out[52]: 
array([list([]), list([]), list([]), list([]), list([]), list([])],
      dtype=object)
In [53]: arr = np.reshape(arr, (2,3))                                           
In [54]: arr                                                                    
Out[54]: 
array([[list([]), list([]), list([])],
       [list([]), list([]), list([])]], dtype=object)
```

Obvious we could transpose that, but could just as well use (3,2) in the reshape.

Note that this display of `arr` clearly shows that it contains list objects.

But do you really need such an array?  Is it worth the extra work?